# toggle button with animate show / hide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an accordion when you click the button, but need to have animation and just hide the last paragraph. I made a attempt but got one point where I do not know what to do to expand button to animate.

jquery

```
$('button').click( function(){
    $('section p:last-child').show();
    $(this).text('HIDE');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3pwvrhct/)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wjex9gzq/3/

Comment: So you want to have slide effect ? Is it always hide/show the last paragraph or I can utilize its height to show/hide the content ?

Comment: @user26409021 hide/show the last paragraph with animate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('button').click( function(){
    $('section p:last-child').fadeToggle();
    // or you can use $('section p:last-child').slideToggle(); or simply  $('section p:last-child').toggle('slow');
});
```

See your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3pwvrhct/1/)